# How to create a select drop down that opens a URL?

Tags: 8, forms, javascript

I have a select drop down. When the user selects a value from the drop down, the user will then click on a button and based on what the user has selected it will open a url in a new tab. While this is quite simple in JavaScript I am struggling how to figure this out in drupal.

So far I have created a custom module which has a select form and the submit button. From here I am stuck as to how to write if user has selected value a open google.com etc. any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using `$form_state->setResponse()` together with `TrustedRedirectResponse`.

Create the dropdown, like this:

```
$form['select'] = [
  '#type' = 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select'),
  '#options' = [
    'https://google.com' => t('Google'),
    // More links...
  ]
];
```

To open the link in a new tab, you can add this to your form:

```
$form['#attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']];
```

Then create the submit handler, like this:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setResponse(new TrustedRedirectResponse($form_state->getValue('select'), 302));
  // You can change the response code from 302 to whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Wow! Form attributes target blank and it opens a new tab on submit? Nice one 

Comment: @leymannx Thank you! It got the idea from this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709590/submit-a-form-in-a-new-tab.

Comment: Awesome thank you!

Comment: @lolname101 If my answer helped you, please accept it, thanks :)